# iterate through files and name output file after input with extension using python

Tags: python, input, loops, file-extension

newbie python programmer here. I have written a script and want to modify the start so that it runs through files in a folder, so I don't have to change input and output file extensions each time.

The folder of input files contains chromosome files such as 'chr1', 'chr2', 'chrx' etc.
I want to output to a different folder and pathway and use the input files as the basis for the outputfile, while also adding an extension such as 'windowstatistics'. For example then the input file 'chr1' would be output in a different folder as 'chr1windowstatistics'.

I have been trying to solve this for a couple of days without  getting a working solution.

Currently I have:

```
import os
import glob

path = '/man/genotyping/Conservation/splitbychrom/'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, 'Chr*') ):


    inputfile = open(infile, 'r') 
    output = os.rename(inputfile + ".out", 'w')
```

Does anyone know how to get this working, I don't mind if the way it is done is quite different, I just want to be able to run the script once and it iterates through the files.

Please let me know if I need to reformulate the question for clarity. Thanks in advance for all your help. It is really appreciated.

Comment: So, you want the output file to be in another folder, and the to have a name based on the name of the input file. Could you give one example of input/output file names and dirs to make sure I understand what you want ?

Comment: I think you should read the document of os.rename before you asking questiong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write down what you want - which is unclear to me.

1. Do you want to rename? Then tell `os.rename()` what you want to rename and to what. In your case, you want to rename the orognal file to a new name which is certainly not `w`. So do `os.rename(infile, newfilename)`.
2. Do you want to process and put the output data somewhere else? Then open the file for writing, and with the correct file name: do `output = open(infile + ".out", 'w')`.

Especially don't confuse filenames with file objects and how the functions work in particular.

Comment: The above is convenient because your filenames apparently have no extension. If your filenames did have an extension, you could use os.path.split and os.path.splitext to separate filename, extensions, and folder names.

Answer (score 0):

To rename a file:
    os.rename(infile, infile + ".out")

os.rename takes two strings: source path, target path. The assignment to "output" is unused.

To copy a file (in *nix):
    os.system ("cp " + infile + " " + infile" + ".out")

Comment: this feeds the output directly into the terminal

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You want to copy the file? If so, you will have to run exec a system command. Your path looks*nix, so I suggest: os.system ("cp infile infile" + ".out")

Comment: Sorry - typo. To copy, use: os.system ("cp " + infile + " " + infile" + ".out")

Comment: @Tiksi And then you have a `infile` which contains whitespace or quote characters and such stuff, and you are bitten. Better use `subprocess.call(['cp', infile, infile+'.out'])` or [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html).

Comment: @glglgl a very good point. There are more considerations when copying/creating files though, such as: if an additional arbitrary folder was to be injected into the target path that didn't exist. This would be a problem. Such things need to be considered. It was just the general approach of shell copy operation that I was hinting towards, rather than using the ready-made os module.